# flex window size is not getting changed

Tags: apache-flex

I am using flex TitleWindow and I have set its width and height as 100% for both. There is one datagrid placed in this TitleWindow. However, whatever I did to change the window size, it is not getting reflected. Changes are just getting reflected inside the Eclipse design window but not in actual application. Can anyone please suggest something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            verticalScrollPolicy="off"
            title="GanttChart"
            xmlns:project="mpt.project.*"
            showCloseButton="true"
            close="closePopup()"
            >
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mpt.vo.project.GanttChart;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        [Bindable]
        private var styledEditor:IFactory=new ClassFactory(StyledItemEditor);

        [Bindable]
        private var dataForGanttGrid:ArrayCollection;//=new ArrayCollection([{title: "Task 1", start: 0, duration: 3, percentComplete: .7}, {title: "Task 2", start: 1, duration: 3, percentComplete: .5}, {title: "Task 3", start: 2, duration: 3, percentComplete: .3}, {title: "Task 4", start: 5, duration: 5, percentComplete: 0}]);

        public function init():void
        {
            this.dataForGanttGrid=new ArrayCollection();
        }
        public function setDataForGanttGrid(title:String,start:int,duration:int,setPosition:int):void
        {
            this.dataForGanttGrid.addItemAt({title: title, start: start, duration: duration, percentComplete: .7},setPosition);
        }
        private function closePopup():void
        {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox width="100%"
         height="100%">

    <project:GanttDataGrid width="100%"
                           height="100%"
                           max="10"
                           ganttItemEditor="{styledEditor}"
                           taskHeaderWidth="170"
                           dataProvider="{dataForGanttGrid}"/>

</mx:VBox>

</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Comment: TitleWindows are usually intended to be used as pop ups; and in my experience often created in ActionScript.  That said; how are you setting the width and height to 100%?  Using the percentHeight and percentWidth values?  How are you changing the window size?  When you say "not getting reflected" do you mean that the height and width of the title window are not changing or the DataGrid size is not changing?  Or something else?

Comment: Size of TitleWindow and Datagrid, both not getting changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for help.

@Ilya Z: I was implementing your solution only but I didn't want to change the parent's size. I wanted to change size of current element relative to parent element' size.

Here is what I did:

In the mxml file (GanttChartPanel) where I was showing this popup, I added following lines:

```
//previous lines
PopUpManager.addPopUp(gantt,this,true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(gantt);

//New lines    
gantt.height=.8*this.height;
gantt.width= .8*this.width;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(gantt,this,true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(gantt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set  `width="100%" height="100%"` for Application container and all parents of TitleWindow.

Comment: Why would this affect the size of the TitleWindow?

Comment: if you addElement titleWindow in flex application and set width and height as 100%, titleWindow gets parent actual width and height. If you use titleWindow as Popup, that different question

Comment: If you addElement a titleWindow in Flex and set width and height to 100% you'll get a compiler error because "100%" is not an integer.  You must set percentHeight and percentWidth.  In the situation you describe the TitleWindow may not get 100% width/height; because if their are other children to the container they will get allotted some space too in the UI too, regardless of the 100% moniker.  Nonetheless; the question was about changing the size of the TitleWindow; so the initial height/width of the parent containers or the TitleWindow is most likely inconsequential.

Comment: I didn't try to write code, the width and height to 100% is a common expression, it is clear that in the code it will be a compilation error, the rest I not quite understand but thanks for the comment

Comment: @Ilya Z   Please note that I am using this TitleWindow as popup

Comment: @IlyaZ Your statment 'If you use titleWindow as Popup, that different question' helped me to think in another direction and I came to solution, thanks for that.